# Scheduling hourly FW job for finite time | Autosys

Tags: jobs, job-scheduling, autosys

Working with CA Autosys AE.

A file Watcher job **ABC_FW** is defined as below, then this FW triggers **XYZ** job upon success.

```
insert_job: ABC_FW   job_type: FW 
machine: <machine_name>
owner: <owner>
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo, tu, we, th, fr
start_mins: 00
run_window: "09:00-15:00"
watch_file: "/tmp/test.txt"
watch_interval: 60
```

**This FW watcher should not be running after 16:00.**

test.txt is expected to be received on hourly basis but thats not gurantee. The file is recived at any time of the day or it might not be recived at all.

If test.txt is received apart from this "09:00-15:00" i.e. after 16:00, it should pickup only at 09:00, next scheduled time.

I wish to terminate my FW job after 16:00. Which attribute i can use. ?

term_run_time cannot be defined to serve this FW behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To use your term_run_time you can use File Trigger (FT) instead of FW.
Are you only getting 1 file a day or sometimes not at all, you can do term_run_time for 360 minutes which would terminate it 15:00 and then start over again next day at 9:00 and pick it up if file was recived later.